# Trying to refresh a div that is loaded by index.html.erb with js.erb file in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

I am very new to rails, and even newer to trying to get Ajax going.   Up to this point I have been successful in getting a simple ajax call to work to update a div when I click the show link by rendering a partial in the js.erb.  FYI I am using Rails 3.1. This type of thing works for me no problem:

My link:

```
<td><%= link_to "Show", widget, :remote => true %></td>
```

In the controller:

```
def show
  @widget = Widget.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @widget }
      format.js 
    end  
  end
```

In the show.js.erb

```
$("#myDiv").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('widget_detail')) %>")
```

In the _widget_detail.html.erb

```
<div id="myDiv">
 <p>
  <strong>Address:</strong>
  <%= @widget.address %>
 </p>
</div>
```

The issue I am having trouble with now is that I have a section of the site that is rendered by the index.html.erb.    I can't figure out how to get the index.html.erb to refresh with an ajax call.   I think there must be some other java script I need to know, because this does not work unless you are calling a partial from what I can tell.

```
$("#content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('index')) %>")
```

I can get it to do what I want it do do if I make another partial and just dump the exact same thing my index.html.erb has in it. So for instance  I could call it _junk.html.erb and do this:

```
$("#content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('junk')) %>")
```

It will work just fine.  I am sure I am missing something simple, or just need to do something different in the .js.erb file but I am not sure what.   It doesn't make sense to me that I would need to have the same code in two places.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should separate the code that will be reused into a partial and then render the partial in your index.html.erb. Then you can use the partial when you need to refresh that section.